# Counting how many elements in a list of lists satisfy a predicate

Tags: list, prolog

Given a list of lists of integers, e.g. `[[3,10],[3,10,2],[5],[5,2],[5,3],[5,3,2],[5,3,10]]`, I want to go over each sublist and count how many of them sum to 15. In this case that would be 1, for the sublist `[3,10,2]`.

I am aware of the predicate `aggregate_all/3`, but I'm having trouble writing a predicate to check each element of the list, what I have now is something like

```
fifteens([X|Xs]) :-
    sum_list(X, 15),
    fifteens(Xs).
```

and within another predicate I have:

```
aggregate_all(count, fifteens(Combinations), Value).
```

where `Combinations` is the list of lists of integers in question.

I know my `fifteens` predicate is flawed since it's saying that *all* elements of the nested list must sum to 15, but to fix this how do I take out each element of `Combinations` and check those individually? Do I even need to? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your `fifteens/2` predicate has no because for empty list and thus it will always fails because due to the recursion eventually `fifteens([])` will be called and fail.

Also you need to change completely the definition of fifteens, currently even if you add base case, it says check **ALL** elements-sublists to see if they sum to 15. That's Ok but I don't see how you could use it with aggregate.

To use `aggregate/3` you need to express with `fifteens/2`, something like: *for every part of my combinations list check separately each sublist* i.e each member:

```
ifteens(L) :-
    member(X,L),
    sum_list(X, 15).
```

Now trying:

```
?- aggregate_all(count, ifteens([[3,10],[3,10,2],[5],[5,2],[5,3],[5,3,2],[5,3,10]]), Value).

Value = 1.
```

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot for the explanation! I was already aware of the flaws in my logic but I wasn't sure how to work around it, never worked with nested lists in Prolog before.

Comment: @Veins, glad that helped ;-) !!

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for ... [`foldl/4`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foldl/4). Functional programming idioms in logic programming languages? Yes, we can!

First, summing the summable values of a list:

```
sum_them(List,Sum) :-
   foldl(sum_goal,List,0,Sum).

sum_goal(Element,FromLeft,ToRight) :- 
   must_be(number,Element),
   must_be(number,FromLeft),
   ToRight is Element+FromLeft.
```

Then, counting the ones that sum to 15:

```
count_them(List,Count) :-
   foldl(count_goal,List,0,Count).

count_goal(Element,FromLeft,ToRight) :- 
   must_be(list(number),Element),
   must_be(number,FromLeft),
   sum_them(Element,15) -> succ(FromLeft,ToRight) ; FromLeft = ToRight.
```

Does it work? Let's write some unit tests:

```
:- begin_tests(fifteen_with_foldl).

test("first test",true(R==1)) :-
   count_them([[3,10],[3,10,2],[5],[5,2],[5,3],[5,3,2],[5,3,10]],R).

test("test on empty",true(R==0)) :-
   count_them([],R).

test("test with 2 hist",true(R==2)) :-
   count_them([[15],[],[1,1,1,1,1,10]],R).

:- end_tests(fifteen_with_foldl).
```

And so:

```
% PL-Unit: fifteen_with_foldl ... done
% All 3 tests passed
true.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll be sure to keep this in mind.